# HTML5 Draggable List - multiple setData?

Tags: javascript, draggable, html5-draggable

So, I have a list of bands that I want to organise into a running order, like so:

```
<li data-band-id='1' draggable='true' class='band-name'>Metallica</li>
<li data-band-id='2' draggable='true' class='band-name'>Slayer</li>
<li data-band-id='3' draggable='true' class='band-name'>Paradise Lost</li>
<li data-band-id='4' draggable='true' class='band-name'>Gojira</li>
```

I would like to be able to drag these list items around to change each bands placement within the overall list. So far, I have the following JavaScript to do this:

```
var dragSatMS = null;
function handleDragStart(e) {
    //this.style.color = 'green'; 
    dragSatMS = this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.innerHTML);
}
function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    return false;
}
function handleDragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add('over');
}
function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over');
  //this.style.color = '#333';
}
function handleDrop(e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  if (dragSatMS != this) {
    dragSatMS.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  }
  return false;
}
function handleDragEnd(e) {
  [].forEach.call(mssatCols, function (mSatCol) {
    mSatCol.classList.remove('over');
     //mSatCol.style.color = '#333';
  });
}
var mssatCols = document.querySelectorAll('#ms-saturday .band-name');
[].forEach.call(mssatCols, function(msSatCol) {
  msSatCol.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  msSatCol.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  msSatCol.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  msSatCol.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  msSatCol.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  msSatCol.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

This works perfectly, I can drag and drop lists to make them change places and the name of the band swaps appropriately.  However, the value of the 'data-band-id' attribute stays as it was. I know this is exactly what the code I have does and thats my issue. I'd like to amend the code so that both the name of the band being dragged and dropped **and** the value of the 'data-band-id' attribute are swapped.

I've Googled a lot but found nothing that can show me how to setData on multiple values, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the `attributes` property of both items and access the value of `data-band-id`. Once you have both two values, you can call `setAttribute("name", "value")` to update the `data-band-id`. Your updated `handleDrop` method would then be:

```
function handleDrop(e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  if (dragSatMS != this) {
    dragSatMS.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    //Get the data-band-id of both items.
    itemToReplaceAttr = this.attributes["data-band-id"].value;
    draggedItemAttr = dragSatMS.attributes["data-band-id"].value;
    //Call "setAttribute" to update the attributes.
    this.setAttribute("data-band-id", draggedItemAttr);
    dragSatMS.setAttribute("data-band-id", itemToReplaceAttr);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here's a demo for good measure: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/bh4t68d9/)**

Comment: The following fiddle supports this answer further: https://jsfiddle.net/yw07rhcm/

Comment: Thank you both very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Yass' answer is one way of solving the problem.

But I will now introduce another method to you that all tutorials I have seen on drag-and-drop carefully avoid - I believe the usage of drag-and-drop API provides an ideal scenario where event delegation should shine - however, till date (and as far as I know) none of the popular tutorials have explored that approach.

If you're in a hurry to see my suggestion working, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7c9cpv9g/).

So, you may delegate the handling of the drag events to the parent of the items, `ul`. And instead of swapping the `innerHtml` of the dragged element with that of the element dropping will occur on, swap the **`outerHtml`**.

```
var draggedItem = null;
var ul = document.getElementById('ms-saturday');

// delegate event handling to the parent of the list items
ul.addEventListener('dragstart', buffer(handleDragStart), false);
ul.addEventListener('dragover', buffer(handleDragOver), false);
ul.addEventListener('drop', buffer(handleDrop), false);

function handleDragStart(e) {
  draggedItem = e.target;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

  // dataTransfer is not really required, but I think IE may need it.
  // Also, not that if you must use dataTransfer API,
  // IE strongly requires that the mime type must be 'text'.
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.innerHTML);
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

  return false;
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  var tmp;

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  if (draggedItem !== e.target) {
    // swapp outerHtml here
    tmp = draggedItem.outerHTML;
    draggedItem.outerHTML = e.target.outerHTML;
    e.target.outerHTML = tmp;;
  }

  return false;
}

// this is used to create the handlers so that there won't be
// a need to repeat 'if (e.target === ul) {...' for as many times
// as there are handlers needed.
function buffer(fn) {

  return function(e) {

    // ignore drag-and-drop on the parent element itself
    if (e.target === ul) {
      return;
    }

    fn.call(this, e);
  };
}
```

I leave you to refine this approach to your taste.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it very much.